# Simultaneous call of recursive function for two objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I created a recursive function, which animate an object with some mathematical laws:

```
var pi = Math.PI; 
var divisions = 36;
var inc = pi/divisions;
var t=pi/2;
var i = 0;
var loopNumber = 0;
var time = 50;


function updateTime(obj, alp)       {

    obj = obj;
    alpha = alp;

    x1 = //some mathematical calculations, x1 = f (t, alpha);
    y1 = //some mathematical calculations, y1 = f (t, alpha);

    if (loopNumber ==5) {
        obj.stop();
        return
    }

    if (i == divisions*2) {
        t=pi/2;
        i=0;
        loopNumber++;
    }

    t+= inc;    
    i++

    obj.animate({
        top: y1,
        left: x1,
    }, time, 'linear', updateTime(obj, alpha))


}
```

It works perfect for one object:

```
$(window).load( function() {
        updateTime($('#runner1'), pi/4);
    }
)
```

But when I tried to call this function for two objects - I faced with a trouble - it always works for one object. Another object don't animate:

```
$(window).load( function() {
        updateTime($('#runner1'), pi/4);
        updateTime($('#runner2'), -pi/4);
    }
)
```

Can you explain plese - why?
How to make it work simultaneously for several objects?

HTML is:

```
<div id="runner1" style="height: 20px; width: 20px; border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 0 0 13px gold; background-color: cyan; z-index: 1; position: absolute; margin-left: -10px;  margin-top: -10px;"> </div>
<div id="runner2" style="height: 20px; width: 20px; border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 0 0 13px red; background-color: violet; z-index: 1; position: absolute;  margin-left: -10px;  margin-top: -10px;"> </div>
```

Comment: That doesn't even work properly for one - you should be passing a call to animate - what you're currently passing is `undefined`. It just happens to work because you queue the entire animation sequence before it begins.

Comment: I wonder how this code may works for you. 4th parameter of [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method should be `Function`. Whereas `updateTime(obj, alpha)` in your code is **value**

Comment: Hi guys.
Thank you for responses.
I understand, that in callback of animate I should pass simply `updateTime` instead of `updateTime(obj, alpha)` - is that what you talking about?

But in this case `updateTime()` can't get an input parameters `obj` and `alp`. How to do in this case?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the recursive call inside an anonymous function, otherwise it is executed immediately when animate states. It is purely because the animations are queued for the same element that it even works for one item:

```
    obj.animate({
        top: y1,
        left: x1,
    }, time, 'linear', function(){updateTime(obj, alpha);})
```

e.g.

```
function updateTime(obj, alp)       {

    obj = obj;
    alpha = alp;

    x1 = //some mathematical calculations, x1 = f (t, alpha);
    y1 = //some mathematical calculations, y1 = f (t, alpha);

    if (loopNumber ==5) {
        obj.stop();
        return
    }

    if (i == divisions*2) {
        t=pi/2;
        i=0;
        loopNumber++;
    }

    t+= inc;    
    i++

    obj.animate({
        top: y1,
        left: x1,
    }, time, 'linear', function(){updateTime(obj, alpha);})


}
```

Note: Accessing a global variable for the loop will cause you problems. You should pass a countdown as well and pass `countdown-1` to the recursive calls. *I am not sure what some of your other variables are doing, so you may be able to remove more code now:*

```
function updateTime(obj, alp, countdown)       {

    obj = obj;
    alpha = alp;

    x1 = //some mathematical calculations, x1 = f (t, alpha);
    y1 = //some mathematical calculations, y1 = f (t, alpha);

    if (!countdown) {
        obj.stop();
        return
    }

    if (i == divisions*2) {
        t=pi/2;
        i=0;
    }

    t+= inc;    
    i++

    obj.animate({
        top: y1,
        left: x1,
    }, time, 'linear', function(){updateTime(obj, alpha, countdown-1);})


}
```

and use like this (to run each with 5 animations):

```
$(window).load( function() {
        updateTime($('#runner1'), pi/4, 5);
        updateTime($('#runner2'), -pi/4, 5);
    }
)
```